# Can we use fmap in javascript in obiee?

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

I want to add a background image to dashboard but by using fmap instead of using analyticsRes. Is it possible to do so? Can any javascript help in that just like it do for analyticsRes?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Oracle support document [1352485.1 – Displaying Custom Images Using Fmap](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1352485.1), any image you want to display using fmap needs to be under the style directory (e.g. \obiee\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\web\appv2\res\s_blafp\images) and under the admin server directory thought the exact location depends on the version you're running.

Answer (score 0):

We can add images to dashboards by two ways.

1. By using fmap path :
   In this case the file needs to be placed in OBIEE Presentation Server.
2. By using a url in  tag :
    tag of html can use both the image placed in OBIEE Presentation Server and also an image from any other web server.
   For example:
   Add a text into your dashboard section. Contains HTML Markup check box should be ticked.

Just add below snippet in the text:

```
<div id="my_logo" style="margin-left: 100px;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmHl0.png" width=50 height=50></div>
```

This will add an image from Stack site to your dashboard. In similar way any other image can be added as background image.